# Ajax FileUploader

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am having an update panel and I need to go for a fileUpload control. Well, as the normal fileupload doesn't work properly with the update panel I thought of going for an ansynchronous file uploader control from the AJAX toolkit. But I am not very good at AJAX.

Comment: This old question can be put on hold as "needs more focus".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event you need to worry about is the "OnClientUploadComplete" event. In that event you can save your file.

Remember that for an Ajax control, you have to add your Ajax Script Manager to the top of the page.

And if you have an ajax script manager, you dont need to add (and i think you can't add) more script managers. this includes the regular script manager, you dont need to add that.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this...
http://asp.net-informations.com/ajax/ajax-AsyncFileUpload.htm

**Edit:** Coding part will work the same as a Normal Fileupload control. Like...

```
if(FileUpload1.HasFile)
{
   FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/AppFolderName/" + FileUpload1.FileName));
}
```

Comment: Make sure, if you use AJAX, you have to Add ScriptManager at the top of page.